# jetty (WebSocket) Binary frame aggregation disabled

Tags: binary, websocket, jetty, frame

I was trying to use Jetty WebSocket for binary upload.
I already have some client and server code. It works fine if I send small binary sizes, but if I try to send a long binary Jetty send a error message:

> "Binary frame aggregation disabled"
>
> WARN:oejw.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455:Frame discarded. Binary aggregation disabed for SCEP@fdbc27{l(/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51199)<->r(/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8081),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{WebSocketServletConnectionRFC6455 p=WebSocketParserRFC6455@1264bf5 state=DATA buffer= g=WebSocketGeneratorRFC6455@144d0c6 closed=false buffer=-1}

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by implementing the `WebSocket.OnFrame` interface. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. What I did is changing the `MaxBinaryMessageSize` property of a connection using something like `this.connection.setMaxBinaryMessageSize(163840000)`...The default value is 16384.

So what I concluded is that the binary message I have exceeds the maximum size defined in the WebSocket. So, one option is modifying MaxBinaryMessageSize and another is using implementing the `WebSocket.OnFrame` interface to split the message to several frames.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `WebSocket.OnFrame` seems to have helped me as well. It's very easy. In your `onHandshake()` you just remember your `connection` (or you can do it in `onOpen()`). You use `WebSocket.FrameConnection` in `onFrame()` to cope with the data you received. That's all :) .

Answer (score 0):

Putting larger `bufferSize` into init-params of `WebSocketServlet` solved this problem for me.